# Show results from two joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I have two tables, machines and images, which are joined by a common field 'machine_id'

If I create the following query;

```
SELECT
machinery.ref_no,
machinery.make,
machinery.model,
images.image_name
FROM images
INNER JOIN machinery
ON images.machine_id = machinery.id
WHERE machinery.ref_no = 1234
```

I get the following result as expected given the machine has three images associated with it;

```
Ref_no   make   model    image_name
1234     Ford   Mustang  image111.jpg
1234     Ford   Mustang  image112.jpg
1234     Ford   Mustang  image113.jpg
```

I need to somehow get the result to display like this;

```
Ref_no  make  model    image_name    image_name    image_name
1234    Ford  Mustang  image111.jpg  image112.jpg  image113.jpg
```

My reason for wanting this is, the application I'm using (Wappler) allows the creation of an XML file from a MySQL query. The result I need to try and replicate is as follows;

```
<machines>
<ref_no>1234</ref_no>
<make>Ford</make>
<model>Mustang</model>
<Files>
<Image>111image.jpg</Image>
<Image>112image.jpg</Image>
<Image>113image.jpg</Image>
</Files>
</machines>
```

I know the XML above contains a  section and I have no idea how to create this with the SQL query, perhaps someone out there can help me which would be fantastic!

I have looked at pivot tables but my SQL knowledge is too limited to work out whether this is the correct way of going about this

Comment: is it fine if you have 1 image column, containing all three images ?

Comment: I'm not sure having all the images in one column will work, the end result for me is to be able to generate an xml file similar to that shown. Also note that a machine may have more or less than three images.

Answer (score 0):

Building an xml string with grouping

```
select concat ('<machines> <ref_no>',Ref_no,'</ref_no><make>',make,'</make>'
  , '<model>',model,'</model>','<Files><Image>'
  , group_concat(image_name SEPARATOR '</Image><Image>')
  , '</Image></Files></machines>') xml
from (values
  row (1234, 'Ford', 'Mustang' ,'image111.jpg'),
  row (1234, 'Ford', 'Mustang' ,'image112.jpg'),
  row (1234, 'Ford', 'Mustang' ,'image113.jpg') 
) tbl(Ref_no, make, model, image_name)
group by Ref_no, make, model
```

Comment: The application I'm using (Wappler) has an app which creates an xml file from an SQL query so I can't use the above, I just need an SQL query that gives a result as shown.